# migrar sitio completo de mysql a mysqli

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Buen día genios de la programación, tengo un problema y grave.
resulta que tengo una pagina web y sistema de registro de datos dentro de la pagina web, todo esta echo en php y mysql.

resulta que el sistema de registro se ha caído, y luego de haber leído e investigado un poco, concluyo que fue por el vencimiento de consultas con mysql, ya que ahora hay que migrar a mysqli.

La cuestión del millón es:

todo el sistema esta diseñado con consultas mysql, más de 50 reportes que tienen consultas con mysql.
entonces tendré que estar pagina por pagina haciendo los cambios de las consultas mysql y editándolas por mysqli, O existe alguna forma más sencillo de migrar todo el sitio en ese aspecto.

Comment: Hola, con todo respeto, creo que la pregunta es más que clara, de echo ya un miembro le entendió claramente y me ha dado una buenas respuesta. nunca he hablado de drivers por cierto.

saludos y gracias mil por responder.

Comment: Si es por una actualización a PHP7 y te marca que las funciones mysql_* no están definidas, incluye en tu proyecto [el archivo fix_mysql.inc.php](https://github.com/rubo77/php-mysql-fix), que es simplemente una *"envoltura"* a `mysqli`.

Comment: Hola Sal, mil gracias, era la respuesta que andaba buscando, no sabes como acabas de salvarme la vida.
te agradezco muchísimo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es por una actualización a PHP7 y te marca que las funciones mysql_* no están definidas, incluye en tu proyecto el [archivo fix_mysql.inc.php](https://github.com/rubo77/php-mysql-fix), que es simplemente una *"envoltura"* a `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que por la versión de *PHP* ocupada en tu servidor donde esta alojado tu desarrollo ya no lo ejecuta, lo que te recomiendo es que realices el cambio de todas las MySQL -> Mysqli teniendo en cuenta que cambia no solo el nombre si no el orden de los parámetros.

**Ejemplo:**

```
mysql_query($datos);
```

Deberá cambiar por:

```
mysqli_query($conexion, $datos)
```

También ten en cuenta que tendrás que cambiar *mysql_fetch_array*, y con estos cambios y debería poder correr correctamente tu aplicativo.

Comment: Hola CJulián, primero que nada, muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder. en efecto es lo que ya había investigado, pero imagina estar cambiando más de mil consultas de mysql por mysqli, es una completa locura tío.
mi pregunta es, si alguien sabe, si no existe algún software, truco o lo que sea, para intentar hacer una migración de una sola vez, ya que es una locura estar cambiando de mysql a mysqli una por una, es desesperante y me tardare al menos un año para cambiarlo todo.