# Convertir MySQL a MySQLI

Tags: mysql

No tengo nada de conocimiento en este tipo de temas (PHP y SQL) sin embargo quiero probar un proyecto de GitHub en mi localhost (XAMPP) y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in ruta/installer.php:29 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in ruta\installer.php on line 29
```

Uso PHP 7 en XAMPP y por ahí leí que mysql_connect está desactualizado, el problema es cuando lo cambio a mysqli tampoco funciona. Pues me da error tras error, el archivo en teoría debería importar de db.sql a mi base de datos, es todo lo que sé.

```
<?php



// Name of the file

$filename = 'database/db.sql';

// MySQL host

$mysql_host = 'mysql_host';

// MySQL username

$mysql_username = 'mysql_username';

// MySQL password

$mysql_password = 'mysql_password';

// Database name

$mysql_database = 'mysql_database';



// Connect to MySQL server

mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());

// Select database

mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die('Error selecting MySQL database: ' . mysql_error());



// Temporary variable, used to store current query

$templine = '';

// Read in entire file

$lines = file($filename);

// Loop through each line

foreach ($lines as $line)

{

// Skip it if it's a comment

if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')

    continue;



// Add this line to the current segment

$templine .= $line;

// If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query

if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')

{

    // Perform the query

    mysql_query($templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');

    // Reset temp variable to empty

    $templine = '';

}

}

 echo "Tables imported successfully";

?>
```

No solo es en XAMPP, pobré en mi hosting y el error persiste, al parecer todo el código está obsoleto, podían ayudarme a repararlo?:(
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Solo por adelantado, dices haber intentado con mysqli, pero no lo veo implementado, este codigo es con el intento mysqli o no ?

Comment: Tu pregunta ha sido cerrada por tener solución, prueba a hacer la edición, y actualizar a mysqli. Posteriormente, si el intento con mysqli no funciona, podrías actualizar esta misma, o abrir otra pregunta diferente para solucionar problemas.

Comment: [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/424501/migrar-sitio-completo-de-mysql-a-mysqli/425577#425577) una opción muy simple.